# What's the translation of "open-rank position" in French?

Tags: traduction

An open-rank position [means](https://www.chronicle.com/article/how-to-read-a-faculty-job-ad/#:%7E:text=Open%2Drank%3A%20a%20job%20ad,an%20ideal%20rank%20in%20mind.) that:

> the search committee will consider applicants across career stages.

What's the translation of "open-rank position" in French, in the  context of a job post?

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Open-rank) didn't help. [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=open-rank%20position&op=translate) didn't help. Google translate did suggest "rang ouvert" but I barely saw any use of it and some places use it with a different meaning, [e.g.](https://www.mcgill.ca/arts/files/arts/sw_social_welfare_policy-crc_posting_tier_2_-_assistant_professor-fr_finalized.pdf):

> Rang ouvert (professeur adjoint)

---

[Example of use](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/3303335841/):

[image]

Comment: Vous oubliez DeepL : « Le comité de recherche prendra en considération les candidats à tous les stades de leur carrière. »

Comment: « open-rank position → candidature libre » i.e. non soumise aux critères de pré-sélection autres que les capacités professionnelles relatives au poste proposé.

Comment: j'aurais plutôt dit "candidature ouverte" (par opposition à une candidature devant satisfaire une liste fermé de critère).

Comment: La hiérarchie universitaire étant complexe et hétérogène dans le monde francophone, c'est difficile de répondre sans connaître le contexte de la traduction et le but recherché. On pourrait parler de *"poste ouvert à tous les grades/rangs/statuts"* mais il nous faudrait un ou une spécialiste du (recrutement dans le) système universitaire visé pour trouver la formule exacte...

Comment: @guillaume31 context: job post.

Comment: Close voters: please tell me what details are missing.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt by context I meant more details about your goal: what regional variant of French are you targeting? Academic terms differ a lot from university to university, not to mention between Canada/France/Belgium/... Who's your audience? etc.

Comment: What does it mean to consider applicants _across career stages_? Why the posting from McGill is different from what you're asking (is it because it specifies only one rank or because you feel it says _rank opened : X_)? In the LinkedIn example, is "Mid-Senior level" a range of levels or a a level per se ie. what's the connection between "open rank" and "mid-senior", if there's one?

Comment: @solastalgienitsyne means ass prof, assoc prof or full prof (assuming tenure track). HR always hype reqs.

Comment: @guillaume31 curious to know for any French variant. Audience is applicants.

Answer (score 4):

**Rang à déterminer** ou **Grade à définir** suivi éventuellement de la liste des titres ou niveaux hiérarchiques pour lesquels le poste est ouvert.

***Rang à déterminer*** or ***Grade à définir*** optionally followed by a list of the titles or hierarchical levels suitable for that position.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the options mentioned in the comments, one could say ***sans requis***. The expression indeed does not appear in sources like [*Linguee*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=sans%20requis), as it is apparently a generic substitute for more complete expressions such as: [*sans diplôme requis*](https://www.lesgeiq.fr/lalternance-pour-tous-les-ages-sans-diplome-requis), [*sans qualification requise*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=sans%20qualification%20requise).

Comment: Thanks, open rank doesn't preclude some requirements though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I saw your question in the morning and heard this expression used by someone during the day - it was used in the context of *candidature ouverte* (already mentioned in the comments) for a post in industry, implying that it was open as to *les cadres* as well as to *les techniciens* from the same company.